# Error when update my database

Tags: php, mysql

If I have the following:

> $common = Amelia's sand verbena

When I try to do the following update:

```
$clear=strip_tags($common);
$clear=preg_replace('/[^\w ]/', '', $clear);
$clear=str_replace('  ', '-', $clear);
$clear=str_replace(' ', '-', $clear);
$clear= strtolower($clear);


$sql= "update my_table set sid='$clear' WHERE common= '$common'";
mysql_query($sql) or die("query failed: $sql".mysql_error());
```

I get the following error:

**query failed**: `update my_table set sid='amelias-sand-verbena' WHERE common= 'Amelia's sand verbena'You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 's sand verbena'' at line 1`

Why am I getting this error?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this code.

```
$clear=strip_tags($common);
$clear=preg_replace('/[^\w ]/', '', $clear);
$clear=str_replace('  ', '-', $clear);
$clear=str_replace(' ', '-', $clear);
$clear= strtolower($clear);
$common=str_replace("'", "\'", $common);


$sql= "update my_table set sid='$clear' WHERE common= '$common'";
mysql_query($sql) or die("query failed: $sql".mysql_error());
```

Comment: This code is still vulnerable to SQL injection, see the answers by Yaniro and myself. Doing it this way can and will get you hacked at some point.

Answer (score 1):

The single quote character is part of the SQL syntax.
If you have it in one of your strings you have to escape it with another single quote.
If your string is: 'abc's lalala' it must become 'abc''s lalala', this is a very common issue which can lead to SQL injection problems so use mysql_real_escape_string() on your strings, check it out at http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-real-escape-string.php

Comment: This is wrong, `'abc's lalala` should become `abc\'s lalala` or `abc&quot;s lalala` depending on the output format.

Comment: In http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/string-literals.html it clearly states that single quotes can be written as two consecutive single quotes. &quot; should only be used when displaying the data in HTML/XML, it shouldn't be saved in the database this way, it's redundant.

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, you don't strp or escape quotes. 
Secondly, you're missing a trailing single quote in your query.

```
$sql= "update my_table set sid='$clear' WHERE common= '$common'";
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$safe_common = mysql_real_escape_string($common);
$safe_clear = mysql_real_escape_string($clear);
$sql= "update my_table set sid='$clear' WHERE common= '$save_common'";
```

That does what you need.
Now please go read https://www.php.net/mysql%20real%20escape%20string and https://www.php.net/manual/en/security.database.sql-injection.php . :)

Comment: @fersch Sorry, what? If you mean the slight syntax-error: Thanks, fixed that.